# how to match array in protractor

Tags: arrays, protractor

Spec.js file  :

```
it('validate return-comparison local filters names',function(){
         var namesArray1 = ['Returns Comparison', 'Financials','Quality','Top','10']
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           expect(element.all(by.css('.return-comparison .return-comparison-topbar')).get(i).getText()).toBe(namesArray[i])
        }
        })
```

output:
message:

```
Expected 'Returns Comparison
    Financials Quality
    Top
    10' to be 'Returns Comparison'.
```

> Message:
>       Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 1 elements that match locator By(css selector,
>   .return-comparison .retu rn-comparison-topbar)

How can i compare ?

Comment: The css you're trying to search on is only returning 1 element. Have you investigated if you're getting the elements back that you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Like @S.Huston suggested, there is just 1 element, in the 0th place in your array, that contains all the text. It is not an array of string elements, at least not the way you are looking at it. So instead, you could do:

```
it('validate return-comparison local filters names',function(){
     var namesArray1 = ['Returns Comparison', 'Financials','Quality','Top','10']
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       expect(element(by.css('.return-comparison .return-comparison-topbar')).getText()).toContain(namesArray[i])
    }
    })
```

If you are worried about the order in which they show up, and that only they show up, you could lose the loop and just do

```
.toBe('Returns Comparison Financials Quality Top 10' ).
```

Or if you want to keep close to your original idea, still get rid of .all and then do something like 
`.getText().then(function(text){var partsOfStr = text.split(' ');});` and then compare partsOfStr and your array element by element with expect and .toBe

Comment: You are welcome. Please be aware (I got burned by this) that where you have a string from getText, toContain checks for a substring. But if do getText on multiple elements (at once) that came from elements.all , getText, then that returns an array of strings and toContain checks yours is one of them in its entirety.